# Four Athletes run a race

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Four Athletes $A,B,C$ and $D$ run in a race. They have equal abilities so that all place orderings have equal probabilities. There are no ties

(i) What is the probability that the first two places are taken, in either order, by $A$ and $B$?

My solution:

Total place orderings is $4!=24$

We can have

$A,B,C,D$ or $A,B,D,C$ or $B,A,C,D$ or $B,A,D,C$

so the Prob(the first two places are taken, in either order, by $A$ and $B$)=$4\over{24}$

(ii) The race is run three times, with independent outcomes. What is the probability that the first two places are taken, in either order, by the same two athletes in all three races?

I am having trouble answering the (ii) part, I would appreciate any help

Comment: For part (ii), wait until the first race is over then start counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of outcomes for part (ii) is $(4!)^3=13824$. Now, the first race can have any outcome, so we have 24 possibilities so far. The second race has to have $2\cdot1\cdot2\cdot1=4$ possibilities, since there are two possible runners for the first two spots and then the other two for the last two spots (same calculation you used in part i). The third race has the same number as the second race, so we have

$$\frac{24\cdot4\cdot4}{13824}=\frac{384}{13824}=\frac{1}{36}$$